# Подзапросы в left join doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

Подскажите плиз что делаю не так?
Какие существуют возможности обхитрить Doctriny и через `DQL` использовать подзапрос для left join

Мой код

```
        $subQuery = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('apd')
            ->from(TABLE2::class, 'apd')
            ->where('apd.status = :status')
            ->andWhere('apd.date > :date')
            ->getDql();

        $query =$this->em->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select(
                    "date_format(c.dateCall , '%Y-%m-%d') as date"
                )
                ->from(TABLE1::class, 'c')
                ->leftJoin(
                    sprintf('(%s)', $subQuery),
                    'apd',
                    Join::WITH,
                    'c.column = apd.column'
                )
                ->where('c.dateCall >= :date')
                ->setParameter('date', '2023-07-10')
                ->setParameter('status', 'active')
                ->setParameter('date', $date)
                ->groupBy('p.name, dates')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

Error

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 275 near 'JOIN (SELECT': Error: Subquery is not supported here
```

Comment: Так а в чем проблема перенести условия из subQuery в `where()` для $query?

Comment: @u_mulder, не подходит по условию задачи

Comment: не ясно зачем тут подзапрос, просто джойн и все условия с ним же вместе. Что за условия задачи у вас?

Comment: @teran, мне нужно произвести left join с условием для "правой" таблицы. В случае если запихнуть в where мои условия, то фильтрация произведется по уже полученным данным в результате скрещивания